# Rails 4: Route scope and session cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, scope, routes

If I have the following `routes.rb`:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :foo
end
```

A session cookie is generated:

```
$ curl -s -D - http://127.0.0.1:3000/foo -o /dev/null | grep Set-Cookie
Set-Cookie: _myapp_session=...; path=/; HttpOnly
$
```

But if I change my routes to:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  scope "/bar" do
    resources :foo
  end
end
```

There's no cookie:

```
$ curl -s -D - http://127.0.0.1:3000/bar/foo -o /dev/null | grep Set-Cookie
$
```

What is the relationship between the session cookies and route scopes and how can I keep the same behaviour in both cases?

Comment: I'm afraid you get a 500 internal error or 404 not found in your last example so no cookie can be set.

Comment: Why would I get a 404? `scope` routes /bar/foo requests to FooController.

Comment: I said there may be error but have not said it must be 404. 500 is possible. Why don't you just view it in your browser?

Comment: Of course I saw the site in a browser. The curl command is just an example of usage. Both examples work, minus the generation of the cookie for the second example.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Have you restarted Rails server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Solved my problem. Was something related to the assets prefix. Steps to reproduce:

Create a new rails application:

```
$ rails new sample --skip-active-record
```

Uncomment the therubyracer gem in Gemfile. This is not related to the problem, it's just so we can run the application.

Generate a new resource:

```
$ rails generate resource foo
```

Add some code to the controller that uses the session (`app/controllers/foos_controller.rb`):

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController
    def index
        session[:foo] = 'bar'
        render nothing: true
    end
end
```

Test:

```
$ curl -s -D - http://127.0.0.1:3000/foos -o /dev/null | grep Set-Cookie
Set-Cookie: _sample_session=R1..; path=/; HttpOnly
```

Change the scope of the resource (`config/routes.rb`):

```
Sample::Application.routes.draw do
  scope '/bar' do
    resources :foos
  end
end
```

Test again:

```
$ curl -s -D - http://127.0.0.1:3000/bar/foos -o /dev/null | grep Set-Cookie
Set-Cookie: _sample_session=Sk...; path=/; HttpOnly
```

Change the assets prefix (`config/application.rb`):

```
module Sample
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.assets.prefix = '/bar'
  end
end
```

Test again. No cookies:

```
$ curl -s -D - http://127.0.0.1:3000/bar/foos -o /dev/null | grep Set-Cookie
$
```

Change the assets prefix again:

```
module Sample
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.assets.prefix = '/bar/assets'
  end
end
```

Test again:

```
$ curl -s -D - http://127.0.0.1:3000/bar/foos -o /dev/null | grep Set-Cookie
Set-Cookie: _sample_session=L3...; path=/; HttpOnly
```